# processing list of items in sections

Tags: php

I want 3 item per div (the sample has a total of 7 items) like this:

```
<div>
  <item/>
  <item/>
  <item/>
</div>
<div>
  <item/>
  <item/>
</div>
```

But I can't do

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q){
    ?><item/><?
}

if(++$i%3==1){ 
    //blabla:) 
}
```

Because it incorrectly prints out

```
<div>
  <item/>
  <item/>
  <item/>
</div>
<div>
  <item/>
...
```

How do I correctly print out the items in blocks of 3?

Comment: This can't possibly be all the relevant code.  Where do you print the `<div>` and `</div>`?

Comment: Please have a look at Stackoverflows [How to Ask resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors, but I can't tell if that's your actual code or something you typed out in 10 seconds as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were most of the way there.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ....");

$recordCounter = 0;
$record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
while ($record) {
    if ($recordCounter % 3 == 0) {
?>
    <div class="item-block">
<?php
    }
?>
        <div class="item"></div>
<?php
    $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $recordCounter++;

    if ($record === false || $recordCounter % 3 == 0) {
?>
    </div>
<?php
    }
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: hmm thenk you, i waas dont know this, if($i % 3 == 0).

Answer (score 2):

**somewhat shortened :))**

```
<div class="items">
<?  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ");
    $i=1;
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {
      ?><item /><?
      if($i%4==0){?></div><div class="item"><? }?>
    <? $i++;
    }?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, maybe there are too much php tags =)

```
<?php
$items = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$count = 1;
?>

<html>
<body>
<?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
    <?php if ($count == 1) : ?>
        <div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p><?php echo $item; ?></p>
    <?php if ($count == 3) : ?>
        </div>
        <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $count++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```